# Running a program by class name

Tags: java

We run a Java program by typing `java <programname>`, where `<programname>` denotes the Java class file compiled from my source code. Why can't I simply start the the program by typing `<programname>`?

Comment: if you are so desperate , then you can create a parameterized batch file having " java program" and pass the parameter as program

Answer (score 9):

Java is compiled to bytecode rather than native executable code. As there is no automatic association between the operating system and the generated bytecode, you need a native interpreter to run the code.

Comment: Not exclusive to bytecode. Every modern executable format has an interpreter (for example ld-linux.so.2), there is a lot of meta data that needs to be interpreted (binary format, dependencies, ...) before the program can be executed. Only difference with java is missing build in support of the host OS.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in teaching the operating system how to handle .class files (silently invoking the interpreter). For some reason it was just not done for windows.

Comment: C python clearly is interpreted too I'm sure we all agree but doesn't have these limitations (on Windows you have to change a setting though). Actually never thought about if this can be done for java programs too..

Comment: It's not done under *nix platforms either though

Comment: If only Sun had defined the class file magic number to be 0x2321202f7573722f62696e2f6a6176610a ...

Answer (score 4):

System expects a native executable command, it does not understands .class files.

For Java, native executable files are provided in /bin/ directory in your JRE installation.

Class files run on JVM, not on underlying system. This "java" executable starts JVM and loads provided class to it.

Answer (score 1):

Java programs always runs in JVM and "java" command invokes JVM. JVM is a virtual machine means logical machine in your physical one which means your program name is direct command to the virtual machine (logical machine). In java programs are compiled to byte code which is machine code for the logical machine (JVM) so it can be executed directly on virtual machine (JVM) not on the operation system. your java programs not machine code for your operating system and thats why you can not run your java program directly by placing program name on command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Because a .class file isn't recognised as an executable file on windows. However the program java is a .exe (so windows knows it is an executable), so you type java to launch the java program and the tell it top open your .class file.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "glue" present in Windows (as shipped by Microsoft) that lets it know how to map your `command` into executing your `command.class`.  Hence you must do the invocation yourself.

Note that some Java installations allow clicking on jar files (which are zip files holding class files) to run the application inside.